# Should we use donate button for our free scripts and application

Tags: paypal

First i am not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question , but i found couple of donation questions here. So i thought i should ask it on stackoverflow, but if i am wrong please refer me to the correct stack exchange network site.

We are a group of people who are creating web scripts and applications for free downloads, we never charge anyone. But sometimes it's really hard to spend on a project we are not going to earn. So is it a good idea to use paypal donate button on our site or not.

Apart from me and some of my fellows we have some other volunteers as well who have been creating these free web applications so we need some way to encourage them and pay them some little amount for their hard work. As we have no earnings from the site it is not possible to pay them directly.

Can someone suggest a better way to encourage all the contributors as i found that donate button will be helpful . Still i am not sure and do not want to take any wrong steps

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [Flattr](https://flattr.com/). It's something between PayPal for small donations and a Facebook Like button:

If a user clicks on it, Flattr will remember that website and, at the end of the month, all people "flattred" by that user will receive a certain financial donation from that user. The benefit of this system is that your users only would have to click once to show their support (both morally and financially). Also with Flattr all money a user wishes to spend will reach you (and hopefully also your volunteers), fee's are paid when putting money on your Flattr account.

Due to its (rather high) fees, I would only recommend PayPal if you expect larger donations.